# read file binary in xna?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, binary

I want read 10 byte start at x in *fileName* and save into bitLevel
I write that:

```
byte[] bitLevel = new byte[10];
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
       fileStream.Read(bitLevel, x,10);
       //some code
}
```

but nothing in bitLevel, I am lost?

Comment: Perhaps instead of dealing with the bits directly, make a StreamReader and StreamWriter for your FileStream. They greatly simplify read/write functions.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
It sounds like your program may not be looking in the right place for the file.  Try adding the following before you open the file to verify the full path of the file and whether or not it exists.  If this is the problem, check the **Working Directory** under the **Debug** tab of your **Project Properties**.

```
fileName = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(File.Exists(fileName), "Error: Could not find " + fileName);
```

---

The second parameter of the **Read** function specifies the byte offset in array at which the read bytes will be placed.  It does not specify an offset in the stream to read from.  Use the **Seek** function to set the read position of the stream.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   fileStream.Seek(x, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   fileStream.Read(bitLevel, 0, 10);
   //some code
}
```

Comment: @Sunary any exception? or bitLevel is just empty? By the way, are you sure you got the file path right? Getting the path of a file outside windows is a pain in the neck using plain old streams

Comment: I think its can't into using(){}, because I set value of test: using(){test = 1;}, but not change?

Comment: @Empyrean .My file name is: _string fileName = "levels\\";
            switch(iChap){
                case 1: fileName += "beginner.dat";
             break;
                case 2: fileName += "normal.dat";

            }_ and my binary file is not empty

Comment: @Sunary  It sounds like your program may not be looking in the right place for the file. I've updated my answer to address this.